# Mockito for Resttemplate exchange method

Tags: java, rest, mockito

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
public void getWebDlpPoliciesTest() throws Exception {
    String responseValue = "{\n" +
            "    \"policies\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"lastUpdatedBy\": \"15678000\",\n" +
            "            \"lastUpdatedTime\": \"test@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "            \"description\": \"This rule set blocks the transfer of sensitive information outside your organization's network based on DLP Classifications that McAfee maintains and that you can configure.\",\n" +
            "            \"publishedStatus\": \"PUBLISHED\",\n" +
            "            \"enabled\": \"true\",\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"DLP Classification\",\n" +
            "            \"id\": \"DLP_Classification_Rules\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t]\n" +
            "}";
    ResponseEntity<Object> stringResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(responseValue, HttpStatus.OK);
    when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), HttpMethod.GET, anyObject(), (Class<Object>) anyObject())).thenReturn(stringResponse);
}
```

---

**Error:**

```
getting error like org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
```

Comment: You can't use 3 matchers and one literal. Wrap `HttpMethod.GET` like `eq(HttpMethod.GET)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.GET)` to the `HttpMethod.GET` in the stubbing as shown below

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
public void getWebDlpPoliciesTest() throws Exception {
    String responseValue = "{\n" +
            "    \"policies\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"lastUpdatedBy\": \"15678000\",\n" +
            "            \"lastUpdatedTime\": \"test@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "            \"description\": \"This rule set blocks the transfer of sensitive information outside your organization's network based on DLP Classifications that McAfee maintains and that you can configure.\",\n" +
            "            \"publishedStatus\": \"PUBLISHED\",\n" +
            "            \"enabled\": \"true\",\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"DLP Classification\",\n" +
            "            \"id\": \"DLP_Classification_Rules\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t]\n" +
            "}";
    ResponseEntity<Object> stringResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(responseValue, HttpStatus.OK);
when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), eq(HttpMethod.GET), anyObject(), (Class<Object>) anyObject())).thenReturn(stringResponse);
}
```